# Material icons not displayed - Quasar

Tags: html, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar, google-material-icons

I have a quasar project in which the material icons are being displayed as text instead of icons.
I did install the packages using npm. Even though, it is not working.

Below is my app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

require('quasar/dist/quasar.css');
require('quasar/dist/quasar.min.css');

import Quasar from 'quasar';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vue from 'vue';

import Plugin from '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/index.css';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/eva-icons.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/fontawesome-v5.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/ionicons-v4.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/material-icons-outlined.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/material-icons-round.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/material-icons-sharp.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/material-icons.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/mdi-v4.umd.js';
import '@quasar/quasar-ui-qiconpicker/dist/icon-set/themify.umd.js';

Vue.use(Plugin)

Vue.use(Quasar);
Vue.use(Vuetify);


/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('example-component1', require('./components/Com.vue').default);
Vue.component('example-component2', require('./components/Comp.vue').default);


let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
        },
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your quasar.conf.js, you must specify which icon set you'd like to use -- you have several options outlined within that file.  Then, make sure when you're specifying the icon names, they match what the icon name is on the material design web site.  I also see that you're importing ALL of the icon sets when you only need Material -- which may be a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added material icons font to the document?
https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&yav=40bde127

Comment: <link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

I have added this to my head.blade file

Comment: You can also check that page: https://quasar.dev/options/installing-icon-libraries

Comment: You are asking about material icons, but added to head fontawesome icons

Comment: Shoot!
Thanks for that.